# Why is pig filtering out empty string despite not asking it to?

Tags: filter, apache-pig, hdfs

I am trying to filter out data using the pig filter method. However I do not want to filter out empty strings. The following filter is filtering out what i want it to but it is also filtering out (action matches '') which i am not asking it to. Any way around this?

```
filtered = filter distinctVals by not ((action matches 'Identified') or (action matches 'Initiated') or (action matches 'Completed'));
```

Comment: I want it to exclude only those 3 actions. However it is also excluding if the action is the empty string.

Comment: If the answer was useful you can click the up arrow. If it solved your problem, you can click the checkmark icon.

Answer (score 0):

Filters are not working like "filter out". They work by "filter in".

You can see that from the [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_filter_operator.htm). The result of the filter

```
filter_data = FILTER student_details BY city == 'Chennai';
```

are only items that **have** Chennai:

```
(6,Archana,Mishra,23,9848022335,Chennai)
(8,Bharathi,Nambiayar,24,9848022333,Chennai)
```

Your code should therefore exclude the `not`:

```
filtered = filter distinctVals by ((action matches 'Identified') or (action matches 'Initiated') or (action matches 'Completed'));
```

Comment: alright, so I have tried to "filter in" however I have no way of filtering in an empty string.                                                                                             filtered = filter distinctVals by ((action matches 'Errored') or (action matches 'Failed') or (action matches ''));  does not include my results with empty string

Comment: @Pxl: then use `==` instead of `matches`. `matches` will be a regular expression.